# DNS64/NAT64 WiFi hotspot using Windows

Tags: ipv4, ipv6

Is there a way to have [this option proposed by Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010220-CH213-SW16) available in Windows? I want to test connecting an IPv6-only client to an IPv4-only server on a local environment.

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about host configurations and OSes are off-topic here. Also, we have no control over Microsoft. You should contact Microsoft directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since their "plan" is to create your own NAT64 network, of course. The difference, however, is that Apple builds this *hack* into their OS. To my knowledge, Microsoft has not. But that doesn't stop you from building NAT64 with whatever system/applications/technology available to you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It would be complete if you add suggestions to "system/applications/technology available".

Comment: Product recommendations are off-topic.